# Comparing a PHP array to MySQL database using IN, but only the first result is displayed

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL table

```
|   module  | module_id |
|    301    |      1    |
|    302    |      2    |
|    303    |      3    |
|    304    |      4    |
|    305    |      5    |
|    306    |      6    |
```

The names of the modules are passed to PHP in the form of a JSON array. I'd like to select and display all of the module IDs which are included in the array. So for example, if the modules 301, 303 and 306 are passed to the script, I want to return the values 1, 3 and 6.

I've put together the following script which *almost* works, but unfortunately it's only returning the first value - so if 301, 303 and 306 are in the array, the script is returning '1', rather than 1, 3 and 6.

I'm sure there's probably something pretty basic that I'm missing but can't figure out what it is. Can someone help?

Thanks!

```
$conn = (DATABASE CONNECTION INFO);
$modules = $_REQUEST['modules'];
$insertmodules = json_decode(stripslashes($modules), true);
$inmods = implode(',', $insertmodules);
$getmodsquery = "SELECT module_id FROM modules WHERE module IN ('$inmods')";
$getmods = $conn->query($getmodsquery);

while($row = $getmods->fetch_assoc()) {
 foreach ($row as $value){
  print_r($value);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us output of `print_r($insertmodules);` ?

Comment: Do you have an idea what does $getmodsquery content looks like?

Comment: ...SQL injection as usual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove quote from query and try this line:

```
$getmodsquery = "SELECT module_id FROM modules WHERE module IN ($inmods)";
```

Comment: That's it! I knew it'd be something embarrassingly simple! Thank you! I'll accept the answer in 10 minutes when it lets me!